# Bash unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, file, syntax, eof

I have little to no knowledge in programming and i need some help please.
i have looked through other posts but have been unable to find one that helps.

```
#!/bin/bash
 
session="Golf5"
 
if grep -q /Game/Maps/BR_Paradise "/home/ogvisualz/Servers/logs/termnial.log"; then
  cp /home/ogvisualz/Servers/bkup/Ball5/garden/DefaultEngine.ini /home/ogvisualz/servers/Golf5/Tower/Config/
else
  if grep -q /Game/Maps/BR_Garden "/home/ogvisualz/Servers/logs/termnial.log"; then
  cp /home/ogvisualz/Servers/bkup/Ball5/midori/DefaultEngine.ini /home/ogvisualz/servers/Golf5/Tower/Config/
else
  if grep -q /Game/Maps/BR_Midori "/home/ogvisualz/Servers/logs/termnial.log"; then
  cp /home/ogvisualz/Servers/bkup/Ball5/paradise/DefaultEngine.ini /home/ogvisualz/servers/Golf5/Tower/Config/
else
  if grep -q UNetConnection::Cleanup: "/home/ogvisualz/Servers/logs/termnial.log"; then
  sleep 3
  tmux kill-session -t Ball
else
  if (tmux has-session -t "$session" 2> /dev/null); then
   tmux kill-session -t Ball
else
        unset TMUX && cd /home/ogvisualz/ && ./BallStart
  fi
exit
fi
```

[Pastebin Script](http://pastebin.com/ZB89HJAe)

im trying to make a rotate script (Uploaded to Pastebin) to change a map , but when i run it it keeps spitting out this error.

> ./rotate.sh: line 25: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Any Suggestions?

OS: Ubuntu 15.10 Server x64

Comment: Please post code as well, you tried.

Comment: it looks unreadable when i post it, so i linked it to a PasteBin, its HyperLinked = "Pastebin Script"

Comment: @OGvisualz Ever heard of `elif`?

Comment: @ Biffen No i have not

Comment: @OGvisualz Look it up (`help if`), it could make your code shorter and more readable.

Comment: @Biffen Thank you, i will have a look.

Answer (score 2):

wow wow wow, halt!! why produce so many lines of code, when you can just use elif(else if)???? this is just bad coding guys...

```
if ...; then
  #do_something
elif ...; then
  #do_something
elif ...; then
  #do_something
elif ...; then
  #do_something
elif ...; then
  #do_something
else
  #do_something
fi
exit
```